# Capistrano with only 'sudo su - user' allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sudo

I'm trying to do an uncomplicated Rails/Capistrano deployment to a remote server.  Unfortunately I can't get `sudo` to run correctly out of the box.  I need to deploy here:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user   www       4096 Sep 28 15:05 my_app_dir
```

and sudoers has been set up to allow me to run `sudo su - user` and that's it.

Some attempts to coax this into working from deploy.rb:

```
set :use_sudo, true
set :sudo, 'sudo su - user'  # fails due to bad su syntax, -c is inserted after user
set :sudo, 'sudo -u user'  # fails because it's not set up
set :sudo, 'sudo su - user -c' # also bad syntax
set :sudo_prompt, ''
```

I gather than the best options are to either:

1. Enable password-less `sudo` (recommended [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Significant-Configuration-Variables))
2. Enable `sudo -u user`, which should work with `set :sudo, 'sudo -u user'`

Any ways to make this work as is?

Comment: @whoever is voting to close as "off topic":  from the FAQ, relevant types of questions include "software tools commonly used by programmers".  That would include Capistrano.  The code with the `set :sudo`s is ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

Is your user that you're trying to use added to the sudoers cfg on the server?
Try this

```
run "#{sudo :as => 'bob'} mkdir /path/to/dir"
```

[source](http://rubydoc.info/github/capistrano/capistrano/master/Capistrano/Configuration/Actions/Invocation#sudo_prompt-instance_method)