# How can I switch user in a Capistrano task?

Tags: capistrano, su

I made a small test task below:

```
set :user, "user"
set :password, "password"
set :root_password, "root password"
set :use_sudo, false
role :srv, "exmaple.com"

task :show_info do
    run "iptables -L", :shell => "su -" do |channel, stream, data|
        channel.send_data("#{root_password}\n")
    end
end
```

This server doesn't allow me to use `sudo`, so I have to login as a normal user then become root.

I have also tried to create `surun` from [this article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/07/capistrano-executing-a-command-as-root-without-using-sudo/#comment-42918), though it doesn't help me... :(

Could someone please tell me the promising method to run command after switching to root in Capistrano?

Thanks in advance.

*P.S.* Added the output log:

```
$ cap show_info
  * executing `show_info'
  * executing "iptables -L"
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command
    command finished in 000ms
failed: "su - -c 'iptables -L'" on example.com
```

Comment: just answered a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648611/capistrano-with-only-sudo-su-user-allowed/13321038#13321038

Answer (score 2):

The point is default_run_options[:pty] = true

try this

```
def surun(command)
  default_run_options[:pty] = true
  password = fetch(:root_password, Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("root password: "))
  run("su - -c #{command}") do |channel, stream, output|
      channel.send_data("#{password}\n")
  end
end
```