# Can you use capistrano if you need to sudo su into another user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, sudo

I'm trying to get capistrano working on my groups project. Due to department restrictions, we have to log in as ourselves, then sudo su into a shared project user. That project user that we `sudo su - projectuser` into, has the permissions needed to access the projects directories. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make this work with capistrano. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I talked to the guys over at Capistrano. Apparently it was impossible. I had my sysadmins change our global sudoer file to allow `sudo -u` and that fixed it. Thanks guys.

Comment: I hope this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054076/capistrano-3-change-ssh-options-inside-task/23569541#23569541

Answer (score 1):

```
man sudo

   -u user     The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a user other than root.  To specify a uid instead of a user name, use #uid.  When running commands as a
               uid, many shells require that the '#' be escaped with a backslash ('\').  Note that if the targetpw Defaults option is set (see sudoers(5)) it is not possible to run
               commands with a uid not listed in the password database.

   -i [command]
               The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified in the passwd(5) entry of the target user as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource
               files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution.  Otherwise, an interactive shell is
               executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell.  It also initializes the environment, leaving DISPLAY and TERM unchanged,
               setting HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH, as well as the contents of /etc/environment on Linux and AIX systems.  All other environment variables are removed.
```

Sudo already supports running commands as a specific user, instead of root. So instead of running `sudo mkdir some_folder`, you can simply run `sudo -u your_user mkdir some_folder`, and it will just execute all commands as that user.

Additionally, the `-i` flag will instruct sudo to start a new shell and run the commands. The new shell will be initialized just like a login shell (it will switch to the user's home directory, re-initialize HOME and other variables, etc). Its the closest possible to running `sudo su - your_user`.

To make Capistrano use `sudo -u <your-user> -i` instead of just `sudo`, set the following configuration in your `deploy.rb`:

```
set :use_sudo, true
set :sudo, "sudo -u <your-user> -i"
```

And Capistrano will now use the given user for all sudo commands, with a fresh new login shell.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for a lot of things. For instance when it tries to run the rake assets:precompile command it runs it as the user you logged in as. But since the gems are installed under the shared user account, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following answer:

[How can I switch user in a Capistrano task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741603/how-can-i-switch-user-in-a-capistrano-task)

Of course, you would want to modify that code in order to perform the `sudo su - projectuser` instead of a simple sudo to root.

I've never done this myself, but it seems like it would work.  You could test this out using `cap shell` as well.  Personally, I'd recommend playing around with `cap shell` first.

Additionally, there's another option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648611/capistrano-with-only-sudo-su-user-allowed/13321038#13321038), but I think the original link above provides a better chance of working.